# ImportError: No module named yaml

Tags: ros, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After i recently installed a new version of python, nothing is working in ros. Every time i get import error saying no yaml found. For example, when i run roscore, i get an error as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in

```
from ros import roslaunch
```

File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/**init**.py", line 41, in

```
import roslib
```

File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/**init**.py", line 50, in

```
from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
```

File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py", line 45, in

```
import roslib.manifest
```

File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/manifest.py", line 46, in

```
import roslib.packages
```

File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/packages.py", line 58, in

```
import roslib.os_detect
```

File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/os_detect.py", line 49, in

```
import yaml
```

ImportError: No module named yaml

.............................................................................................

And yes, i have installed yaml.

"sudo apt-get install python-yaml" gives

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

python-yaml is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 107 not upgraded.

.............................................................................................

What could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11557/importerror:-no-module-named-yaml/) by [Kamal](https://answers.ros.org/users/740/kamal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-10-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2011-10-14**:
It sounds like your current version of python doesn't have the yaml module installed. Which distribution and which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you install the new version of python you need to install the version of python-yaml for that version.  Python libraries are installed into different locations for different versions.  Apt-get install will only install the yaml module for your default python.

If your default python is 2.6 it will install into /usr/lib/python2.6  but if you're using 2.7 it will install need the yaml module installed in /usr/lib/python2.7 which is the python 2.7 version of the library.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-16**:
You need tp provide more information on how you "installed a new version of python" for us to help you any more.  It sounds like you did that incorrectly.  Note, I'm just guessing at python versions as you have not mentioned what you're using.  Please see http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [Kamal](https://answers.ros.org/users/740/kamal/) on 2011-10-15**:
I havent separately installed yaml, it came along with python installation. Also I see yaml folders in /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages as well as /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. So i am guessing that yaml is installed for 2.7 also. now what does that mean?

**Comment by [Ruthven](https://answers.ros.org/users/9811/ruthven/) on 2014-05-22**:
If you've yaml present in more than a folder, you've to figure out which is the version you've to use (related to the version of python), and then add that folder in the PYTHONPATH.
At least is what I did to solve the problem.